# Trickery in Logic

Tags: logic

I'm presented with the statement below:
$$\text{If $(a_n)$ is convergent, then $(a_n)$ is monotone and bounded.}$$
I'm then asked to negate the statement, so I make a guess:
$$\text{$(a_n)$ is convergent and $(a_n)$ is not monotone and bounded.}$$

I guess what I'm wondering is...
$$\text{If $(a_n)$ is convergent, then $(a_n)$ is $\overset{\text{...is this "and" a trick?}}{\overset{\downarrow}{\text{monotone and bounded}}}$.}$$

Comment: Its not really a trick, but the statement that $(a_n)$ is monotone and bounded can be written out more fully as follows. [$(a_n)$ is monotone and $(a_n)$ is bounded.]

Comment: I quick check using `[not ( p implies ( q and r ) ) ]` in WolframAlpha makes things clear...

Answer (score 4):

The negation $\neg$ of an "if then" statement is given by:
$$
\neg (p\rightarrow q) \equiv p \mbox{ and }  \neg q
$$

Also remember from De Morgan's laws that
$$
\neg (a \mbox{ and } b)\equiv( \neg a \mbox{ or } \neg b)
$$

If you apply this, the answer should be clear.

Comment: Exactly correct. This is my "guess," as you may notice, but the *and* in the fragment "monotone *and* bounded" is what I feel should be left alone.

Comment: Yes, you can leave 'and'. Meaning ~(a and b) and saying 'is not a and b' isn't very ambiguous, since you'd probably say 'is not a and is b' if you meant (~a and b)